# Compressing a list of integers in Python

Tags: python, list, memory, compression

I have a list of positive (random) integers with the following properties:

Number of elements: 78495

Maximum value of element: 999982

Length of list when converted to a string: 517115 (string looks like "6,79384,238956,...")

Size of list in text file on disk: 520 kb

I am trying to use this list as a precomputed list for an online judge problem because it takes a long time to actually generate this list. However, it is too large to be accepted if I paste it directly into the source code, which has a cap of 50 kb.

I looked into zlib as a way to compress the string but it only seemed to cut the size in half.

Is there a way to really shrink this down so I can unpack it / use it in the source code?

Comment: You say these are random integers. Why do you need these *particular* random integers, and why does it take you so long to just rerun your RNG?

Comment: @user2357112 Random for the sake of this discussion -- getting into the actual math would be outside the question.

Comment: I take it the order is important? If not then the mean difference between values is only 13, so you could try sorting them and compress the deltas.

Comment: Yes, the order is important (to be specific, it is a list of smallest-k values for which 10^k = 1 mod p for primes p > 5). The ith position of the list corresponds to the (i+3)rd prime

Comment: Does your program need the full list, or can it work on a stream of numbers as they come in? In other words, can you set up two threads: 1) a thread that generates smallest-*k* values; and, 2) a thread that consumes/uses those values as they are generated?

Comment: It would need the full list up front

Comment: Not saying it doesn't exist, but I'm not aware of any public compression program that will get you from 520 kB to 50 kB. You might have some luck doing some reading over here: http://mattmahoney.net/dc/

Comment: @user6596353 The question you're really asking is: "Is there a way to make this program run faster by precomputing something, such that the precomputed data doesn't exceed 50KB." To answer that question, of course, we would need to see the program. (We'd need to know how to generate the data you're trying to generate.)

Comment: Yes, the program would be loads faster if I had the precomputed values. I also mentioned above what the values actually are (i.e. 6,2,6,16,18, ..., 999952,499979,124995,333326,999982)

Comment: @user6596353 There are also probabilistic data structures, like a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). It's possible that such an approach is sufficient for your purpose. (It would potentially give false positives, e.g. it thinks a number is in the set when it's not really. But given the domain you're in, I think you could efficiently test whether a number is in fact in the set, so the false positives are easy to deal with.)

Comment: @user6596353 "I also mentioned above what the values actually are"... yeah, but I don't want to spend time actually writing a program to generate them just to see if I can then speed it up by using some precomputed data. :-)

Comment: @user6596353 Are you writing the judging program or the program that is to be judged? If your program is being judged and is failing because it's too slow, perhaps you simply haven't solved the problem correctly?

Comment: @user6596353 I'm intrigued by the problem... if it's a public thing, would you mind sharing a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your definition ...

*it is a list of smallest-k values for which 10^k = 1 mod p for primes p > 5*

... am I wrong to believe that your values are of the form `(p - 1) / x` where x is an integer significantly smaller than p?

For instance, for p < 50, we have:

```
p = 7  : 10^6  = 1 (mod 7)  => k = 6  = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
p = 11 : 10^2  = 1 (mod 11) => k = 2  = (p - 1) / 5  => x = 5
p = 13 : 10^6  = 1 (mod 13) => k = 6  = (p - 1) / 2  => x = 2
p = 17 : 10^16 = 1 (mod 17) => k = 16 = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
p = 19 : 10^18 = 1 (mod 19) => k = 18 = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
p = 23 : 10^22 = 1 (mod 23) => k = 22 = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
p = 29 : 10^28 = 1 (mod 29) => k = 28 = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
p = 31 : 10^15 = 1 (mod 31) => k = 15 = (p - 1) / 2  => x = 2
p = 37 : 10^3  = 1 (mod 37) => k = 3  = (p - 1) / 12 => x = 12
p = 41 : 10^5  = 1 (mod 41) => k = 5  = (p - 1) / 8  => x = 8
p = 43 : 10^21 = 1 (mod 43) => k = 21 = (p - 1) / 2  => x = 2
p = 47 : 10^46 = 1 (mod 47) => k = 46 = (p - 1) / 1  => x = 1
```

The list of x values should compress much better than the list of k values. (For instance, I'd be willing to bet that the most frequent value of x will be '1'.)

And because it's rather easy and fast to compute primes up to 1 million (which I think is your upper bound), you may be able to quickly rebuild the list of k values based on the compressed list of x values and the real-time computed list of primes.

You probably should have explained from the beginning what exactly you were trying to compress to get more accurate answers.

Comment: This is a very good point... I forgot that the orders must divide phi(p) = p-1

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

```
log(2, 999982) ~= 20
```

So the largest number would take 20 bits to store. Let's say that on average, each number takes 10 bits to store (evenly distributed between 0 and the max).

```
~80,000 numbers * 10 bits per number = 800,000 bits = 100,000 bytes
```

So these numbers, stored as efficiently as possible, would take ~100KB of space.

Compression will only work if there's some non-randomness to the numbers. If they're truly random, as you say, then a general compression algorithm won't be able to make this any smaller, so 100KB is about the best you can hope to do.

**EDIT**

Note that things are even worse, in that you want to paste these into source code, so you can't just use arbitrary binary data. You'll need something text-friendly, like base64 encoding, which will add another ~33% of overhead. Also, you can't really store numbers based on the *average* number of bits required, because you'd need some way to know how many bits were used by each individual number. There are possible encoding schemes, but all will carry some additional overhead.

**SECOND EDIT**

Based on the comments above, the data is *not* actually random as originally stated. A general compression algorithm therefore *might* work, and if not, there are presumably other solutions (e.g. just shipping the code that generated the numbers in the first place, which is likely smaller than 50KB).

Comment: What about converting the numbers to other bases, etc?

Comment: Your base-10 numbers are already stored in binary. Any other representation uses the same amount of information.

Comment: @user6596353 Your question doesn't really make sense. Computers store data in binary (base 2), and I was already assuming that representation. E.g. the number 255 (in decimal) is 11111111 in binary, which takes 7 bits to store. That's already the most efficient way to store the number in a computer.

Comment: I'm talking in terms of textual storage (the whole point of this question to begin with). If I have "12345" that's 5 characters. But if I convert it to (for example) hex, it becomes "3039" (one character fewer)

Comment: @user6596353 Right, but I was already talking about storing it directly in binary. I gave a theoretical lower-bound on how much storage it would take.

Answer (score 1):

The [best text compression](http://www.byronknoll.com/cmix.html) available offers a (roughly) 12-17% compression ratio (62.4-90 kB) so you're not going to meet your threshold. Your data are random, as well, which generally makes compression algorithms perform worse.

Look at an alternative approach, such as making your RNG process faster, or if you don't need a full list (just some integers), create a separate "producer" thread to generate random integers (involving whatever actual math you are using) and a "consumer" thread that does work on those integers as they come in. That way, your program could perhaps still do work, even if it would take a long time to generate a full list.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've tested easily availiable algorithms in python on two strings: one is generated randomly with non uniform distribution, another one has some structure. It seems, lzma does better

```
# check the compression ratio
import lzma
import zlib
import gzip
import bz2
import zipfile
import tarfile
compressors = ['lzma','zlib','gzip','bz2'] 
a = np.exp(np.random.rand(1024))
b = np.arange(1024)
b[32] = -10
b[96] = 20000
a = bytes(a)
b = bytes(b)

for i in range(len(compressors)):
    print("{} compression ratio: ".format(compressors[i]))
    a_lzma = eval(compressors[i]).compress(a)
    b_lzma = eval(compressors[i]).compress(b)
    print(float(len(a_lzma))/len(a),float(len(b_lzma))/len(b))
    print("\n")
```

The output:

> lzma compression ratio: 
>   0.93115234375 0.08984375
>
> zlib compression ratio: 
>   0.95068359375 0.1944580078125
>
> gzip compression ratio: 
>   0.9521484375 0.196533203125
>
> bz2 compression ratio: 
>   0.9925537109375 0.1268310546875